# NSubstitute : Mocking REST API, return result based on parameter value

Tags: mocking, servicestack, nsubstitute

I am using NSubstitute  to mock result of servicestack REST API which returns the employee object

```
var mockedCoreService = Substitute.For<jsonClient>(ApiUrl); 

//Create the employee to return for mocking
var employee = new Employeeclass { SSN = "123456789"};

// Get the mocked employee whenver GetEmployee API call is made
mockedCoreService.Get(Arg.Any<GetEmployee>()).Returns(employee);
```

Getemployee API call accepts the Id as a parameter, I want to return different employee based on Id sent.

```
//check the id parameter of GetEmployee and return employee based on the condition in below statement  
    mockedCoreService.Get(Arg.Any<GetEmployee>()).Returns(employee);
```

I am not sure how to do that. Please help.

Thanks,
Amol

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself

```
 mockedCoreService.Get(Arg.Is<GetEmployee>(x=>x.id == 1)).Returns(employee);

 mockedCoreService.Get(Arg.Is<GetEmployee>(x => x.id== 2)).Returns(employee2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach create returned instance "on the fly". `Returns` provide overload methods which accept a function which will return expected value.
So you can generate returned values based on received arguments.

```
fakeService.Get(null)
           .ReturnForAnyArgs(call => new Employee { Id = call.Arg<GetEmployee>().Id });
```